Changing pixels in a Java BufferedImage to transparent
I have a BufferedImage that gets passed into my function (so I don't really know how it's created) and I need to change all of the white pixels to transparent pixels. I'm successfully identifying the white pixels and I run the following code on them:
int rgba = bufferedImage.getRGB(col, row);
      
bufferedImage.setRGB(col, 
                     row,
                     0x00FFFFFF & rgba);

The result is that the pixels are staying white.
I've run toString() on the BufferedImage and get the following (which makes no sense to me).
BufferedImage@26ae880a: type = 1 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=0 IntegerInterleavedRaster: width = 339 height = 356 #Bands = 3 xOff = 0 yOff = 0 dataOffset[0] 0
What do I need to do to make those pixels transparent?

How are you ensuring that this is an image with alpha channel to begin with?

based on given output, it seems to be TYPE_INT_RGB (= 1) which has no alpha channel (confirmed by amask=0)  -- maybe create a TYPE_INT_ARGB image if you need transparency

Note that https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/j2se/1.5.0/jcp/beta2/apidiffs/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html lists the possible types you can get back: there's several types with alpha, but vastly more types without alpha support

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans both type and transparency returned 1. None of this BufferedImage stuff really made sense to me but it seems like I should create an entirely new BufferedImage and simply copy / modify each pixel from the original. Is this the right idea?

@SanderSmith: yes, it's likely a start. Create a new BufferedImage of the same width and height, but one that allows for an alpha channel (the third parameter of the constructor, after width and height), and then draw the image from the original image into the new one, and then set your alphas as required.

@HovercraftFullOfEels Perfect!! It works. Thanks guys, that's the answer.

you could also draw the whole original image on the new BufferedImage instead of copying each pixel, but if you are manipulating all or most pixels anyway, copying is probably more appropriate

As @user85421 suggested:

maybe create a TYPE_INT_ARGB image if you need transparency.

Here is the code for that:
BufferedImage convertToARGB(BufferedImage image) {
    BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(
        image.getWidth(),
        image.getHeight(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    
    // Draw the old image on the new one
    Graphics2D g2d = newImage.createGraphics();
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    
    return newImage;
}

And then you can loop through the pixels and make the white ones transparent like this:
bufferedImage.setRGB(col, row, 0x00FFFFFF & rgba);

Which is exactly what you do. But, there is one issue with this approach. Using setRGB() in loop could be a slow approach. My suggestion is use WritableRaster or if you want to go deeper use DataBuffer like it is suggested here.
Let's first try it with WritableRaster. After creating TYPE_INT_ARGB image, call getRaster() method on that image and loop through that. Like this:
WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
int[] pixel = new int[4]; // Array for storing pixel data (ARGB)

for (int row = 0; row < image.getHeight(); row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < image.getWidth(); col++) {
        raster.getPixel(col, row, pixel); // Get pixel data
        if (pixel[0] == 255 && pixel[1] == 255 && pixel[2] == 255) {
            // Change to transparent (0 alpha)
            pixel[3] = 0;
            raster.setPixel(col, row, pixel); // Set the modified pixel data
        }
    }
}

This will work faster than calling setRGB() repeatedly. Now with the even faster approach using DataBuffer.
DataBufferInt buffer = (DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();
int[] data = buffer.getData();

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] == 0xFFFFFFFF) { // Check if white
        data[i] = 0x00FFFFFF; // Make transparent
    }
}

Working directly with DataBuffer could have it's own issues so use at your own risk.
I've tested all the three methods and they all seem to work. And I compared the performance of them and here are the results:

DataBuffer took 3.8 ms to complete (blazingly fast)
WriteableRaster took 30.7 ms to complete
Simple Loop took 58.4 ms to complete

Hope this helps.

You can make the WritableRaster variant faster by using get/setDataElements instead of get/setPixel. These methods typically uses the same native packed format as the underlying data buffer. A common approach to make things even faster, is to get a full row of pixels at once using these methods. This should get you closer to the performance of the direct array approach, but with the added benefit of not making the image "untrackable".
